# How do I schedule multiple functions to run one after the other, using node-scheduler

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduler

I have 3 functions that I exported. I'm trying to scheduled each function to run every 10 min or once a day. However only function 3 runs and the other 2 get ignored. Any idea Why ?

`const schedule = require('node-schedule')`

`var function1 = require('./path to function.js');`

`var function2 = require('./path to function.js');`

`var function3 = require('./path to function.js');`

```
schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *',function(){
    try {
        function1()
        
        function2()
        
        function3()
         
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
        
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'async await'

```
schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *', async function(){
try {
    await function1();
    
    await function2();
    
    await function3();
     
} catch (error){
    console.log(error);
} });
```